# Как с помощью man просмотреть данные о библиотеке для C++?

Tags: c++, linux, vector, man

Хочу просмотреть базовые библиотеки и их функции для изучения возможностей работы с типами данных, в частности с vector. Решил использовать man в linux, но не понимаю, с какими параметрами.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293737/4827341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартной поставке man-страниц документации к с++ нет.

Можно установить документацию, сгенерированную из заголовочных файлов gcc/libstdc++. Обычно пакет называется как-то вроде [`libstdc++-<версия>-doc`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libstdc++-8-doc). Соответственно справочной страницей для вектора будет `man std::vector`, но, откровенно говоря, эти man-страницы довольно убогие.

Также есть питоний скриптик [`cppman`](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman), который генерирует довольно приличные страницы из [`cppreference.com`](https://en.cppreference.com/) или [`cplusplus.com`](http://cplusplus.com/). Из минусов — он требует доступа к интернету. Он также обычно также есть в репозитариях.

Comment: Я добавлю, что на cppreference.com можно [скачать](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives) сборку документации (то, что есть на сайте) в разных форматах (в том числе, там предлагают и в виде manpages). Мне больше нравится в формате chm (ссылка почти в самом низу страницы).

Comment: @Vladimir, мм.. с виду неплохая штука... нужно будет как-нибудь на досуге опакетить...